# Creating Dynamic TabNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This question has been asked by me before but due to it still not being answered, I am trying my luck again. I was not able to get any solution for this. Basically I want tab navigator to have the navigation dynamically output using an axios api call response. So I want json response to be dynamically added to the navigation. I asked this question on the original repo (and someone else did as well) and got the response to ask the question on stackoverflow.

I am using a tab navigator to display some of the "category" items. The basic Idea is to be able to get those category items from an API call. I have a separate file called, "tabNavigator" which handles the tab navigation. Here is how the file looks like:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator, MaterialTopTabBar } from 'react-navigation';
import Category from '../Screens/Category'
import React from 'react';

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Pizza: {screen: Category, params: {categoryID: 1004}},
    Wine: {screen: Category, params: {categoryID: 1003}}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName:'Pizza',
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeColor: '#f0edf6',
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff4136',
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: 'LoraRegular',
      },
      barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#694fad' },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#2a292d',
      },
    }
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

So what I want to be able to do is Iterate the `Pizza: {screen: Category, params:{categoryID: 1004}},`, Pizza being one of the categories. So suppose if I have an axios data with something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    categories: []
  };
}

getData() {
  const categoryID = this.props.navigation.getParam('categoryID', '404');

  axios.get('http://test.io/category/' + categoryID)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({categories: response.data.category});       
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //log error
    })
}
```

So suppose I had the code above, how would I use this to iterate the category in to the category of my tab navigator? And how can I use this in my existing tab navigator file. Thanks!

Comment: You can set parameters, but is there any reason why you should be dynamic?

Comment: @hongdevelop I know I can set params. But that is not what I want here. In my case, all my navigators are static. Like Pizza, Wine, etc... My Pizza, Wine, Drinks are coming from server api and I want to loop them in my code and not put it statically for each navigation. That is pointless. How can I use the navigation items coming from RestAPI call and loop them in my above code? Sorry if the question is confusing